# open a popup window in mvc asp.net after submitting a form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am not able to open a modal window after submitting. What i have so far is this :
this is my View Permitions.cshtml that is calling that is 
**submiting to Action SalvarPermissoes In controller Admin**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarPermissoes", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <header>
            <h2 id="titulo" name="titulo">@ViewBag.Title  | @ViewBag.UserPrincipal.Name | @ViewBag.UserPrincipal.EmployeeId </h2>
        </header>
        <input name="permissoes_modulos" hidden value="@ViewBag.UserPrincipal.EmployeeId" />
        <table>
            @foreach (var mod in ViewBag.Modulos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><label name="permissoes_modulos" value="@mod.moduloId">@mod.moduloId</label></td>
                    <td><label>@mod.nomeModulo</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="switch">
                                @if (mod.acesso == 1)
                                {
                                    <input name="permissoes_modulos" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" id="@mod.moduloId" value="@mod.moduloId"/>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <input name="permissoes_modulos" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="@mod.moduloId" value="@mod.moduloId"/>
                                }
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="salvar" />
        </div>
    }
```

then my Admin Controller have the action SalvarPermissoes

```
public ActionResult SalvarPermissoes(int[] permissoes_modulos)
{
    int employeeID = permissoes_modulos[0];

    UserManagement userManagement = new UserManagement();
    userManagement.EmployeeID = employeeID;
    userManagement.DeleteUserManagement();

    for(int i = 1; i < permissoes_modulos.Length; i++)
    {
        userManagement.ModuleID = permissoes_modulos[i];
        userManagement.InsertUserManagement();
    }

    return View(); //this target view is suppose to be a modal window
}
```

and this controller is call a view SalvarPermissoes.cshtml which i want to be a modal window using preferentially bootstrap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `SalvarPermissoes.cshtml` view and what does it display? Do you want the popup to be in the same view? (in which case you need to use ajax to submit the form so you stay on the same page)

Comment: right now SalvarPermissoes.cshtml dont have anything, only a `<p>xpto</p>` i would like to stay in the same page, but then i will have to refresh because permitions have changed after submitting. But i have to call with ajax?

Comment: i'm trying with ajax.beginform. If i find the solution i'll post it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use viewBag for sending message from controller to view.
Since ViewBag.Msg is checked for null it will popup the message only after initialize insde SalvarPermissoes action.

```
public ActionResult SalvarPermissoes(int[] permissoes_modulos)
{
 int employeeID = permissoes_modulos[0];

UserManagement userManagement = new UserManagement();
userManagement.EmployeeID = employeeID;
userManagement.DeleteUserManagement();

for(int i = 1; i < permissoes_modulos.Length; i++)
{
    userManagement.ModuleID = permissoes_modulos[i];
    userManagement.InsertUserManagement();
}
ViewBag.Msg = "Thankyou for submitting form";
return View(); //this target view is suppose to be a modal window
}
```

**View**

put this inside top of view

```
@if (ViewBag.Msg != null)
{

    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Post Status</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p >@ViewBag.Msg.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="bootstrapmodel" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="display:none">Open Small Modal</button>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    </script>
}
```

Comment: in the submit button is data-target="myModal" without the #. But thanks man man!!  I cant vote up, i'm less than 15 points, but said it was recorded my vote up.

Comment: Thanks you very much